# Create api using mulesoft studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

How can i create a simple api using mulesoft stodio? I am using the MySql Database and trying to create REST apis and following this tutorial.
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+an+API+for+a+MySQL+Database
But facing the error
Error executing graph: ERROR (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException). Message payload is of type: ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong with your DataMapper definitions, probably a mismatch between the data coming from MySql and the data types for the fields in your DataMapper. Check your data types, the complete error message in Mule Studio, and the output of the Logger between the MySql component and DataMapper if you have a configuration similar to the example in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

i was in assumption that the data mapper source data does not match with the payload it received.

according to error , the data-mapper input is of some format you defined but the received input is of array-list.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the 404 response on the link that you had mentioned in your question.

Your error is not related to what you were asking about How to create Rest API in mule.

As per concern about creating Rest API mule offers two ways:

1. Using the Rest Component (Recommended when you have rest specification defined in java using the jersey or apache-axis)
2. ApiKit Router with RAML (Higly recommended by mulesoft community)

As per your concern about error.

you might have not properly mapped the input fields of datamapper with the outbound messages from DB connector. 
DB Connector always returns the response as ArrayList that need to be caste into any collection like Map or Array.

I recommend kindly use data sense feature of mulesoft DB connector that will automatically map the input fields of data mapper.

if possible share your flow.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the inbound properties of data mapper. output of DB query should not be in unknown format. If it is unknown format, then there is something wrong with your query output.

If you are looking for API creation, then check out the below link.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/walkthrough-design-existing

Answer (score 0):

check the document how to create API

https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/

and regarding the DataMapper error just check the input data type  to the output data type you are mapping. just cross check the input format to output format.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use data weave now . Data mapper is obsolete . Define metadata for your HTTP end by giving some sample JSON and with database you will automatically get metadata extracted by data sense. Now you can use drag and drop for mapping your fields and it will transform input to requited output. you can also look data weave expression generated and now you can change that easily to tweak that.